# get first part of a string in R

Tags: r

I have a string `"00_123.txt"`. I want to get first part of the string before `"."`, that is simply `"00_123"`

I found the `substring("00_123.txt", 0, stop)` can do it. But the problem is that I don't know where to `stop`, because the length of "00_123" can be changed.

How can I do that?

Comment: Did you search before asking this question? http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=get+first+part+of+a+string+in+R

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
x <- "00_123.txt"
gsub("\\..*$", "", x)
[1] "00_123"
```